# rails - converting an object to an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

Hey, I am trying to convert this object to an array of ints e.g. array(3,4,6)

```
- - !ruby/object:Code 
attributes: 
  candidate_id: "3"
attributes_cache: {}

- !ruby/object:Code 
attributes: 
  candidate_id: "4"
attributes_cache: {}

- !ruby/object:Code 
attributes: 
  candidate_id: "6"
attributes_cache: {}
```

here is what I tried

```
result = @intersection.map{|c| c.candidate_id}
```

Thanks

Comment: Your code should work. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I get - undefined method `candidate_id' for [#<Code >, #<Code >, #<Code >]:Array

Comment: Can you give us the result of @intersection.inspect , please? I suspect it is an array of arrays of Code objects, actually.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! --- "[[#<Code >, #<Code >, #<Code >]]"

Comment: Looks like it's an array of array. Try @intersection.first.map...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

- c[:candidate_id]

**OR**

- c[:attributes][:candidate_id]

I'm not familiar with YAML, however you might want to try making hashes instead of Code objects. Additionally, if you do use a code class, you should ensure that you have and attr_accessor (and then your old code should work).

Comment: I get a - undefined method `attributes' for [#<Code >, #<Code >, #<Code >]:Array

Comment: using c[:candidate_id] with a attr_accesser I get a type error (Symbol as array index)

Comment: you do c.candidate_id with attr_accessor